# Static library file not found when linking using CMake

Tags: cmake

I am studying automated testing CppUnit. And I can’t link it with the static library in any way. It's as if some kind of prefix "x64" is added to the file name. I tried using "find_library" and linking directly to the full path (as in the example below) - nothing works. Although in another project linking by file name works fine. What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

My "CMakeLists.txt"

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project("myTest" VERSION "1.0.0" LANGUAGES C CXX)
set(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME})

set(SOURCES 
    "src/main.cpp"
    "src/myFile.cpp"
    "tests/myFileTest.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${TARGET} PRIVATE "headers")

enable_testing()
target_include_directories(${TARGET} PRIVATE "$ENV{CPPUNIT}/include")
target_link_directories(${TARGET} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib")

set(TEST_NAME "myFileTest")
add_test(${TEST_NAME} ${TEST_NAME})
```

Error

```
  [1/1] Cleaning all built files...
  Cleaning... 0 files.
  
  [1/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\src\main.cpp.obj
  [2/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\src\myFile.cpp.obj
  [3/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\tests\myFileTest.cpp.obj
  [4/4] Linking CXX executable myTest.exe
  FAILED: myTest.exe 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\myTest.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\src\main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\src\myFile.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\tests\myFileTest.cpp.obj  /out:myTest.exe /implib:myTest.lib /pdb:myTest.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console -LIBPATH:E:\Programming\C++\Projects\Tests E:\Programming\C++\Projects\Tests\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
  LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\src\main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\src\myFile.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\myTest.dir\tests\myFileTest.cpp.obj /out:myTest.exe /implib:myTest.lib /pdb:myTest.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console -LIBPATH:E:\Programming\C++\Projects\Tests E:\Programming\C++\Projects\Tests\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\myTest.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\myTest.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
E:\Programming\C++\Projects\Tests\out\build\x64-debug\LINK : fatal error LNK1104: can't open file "x64\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib"
```

Root directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sr09.png)

Comment: The file E:\Programming\C++\Projects\Tests\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib doesn't exist. Fix that.

Comment: @273K, this file is in the root directory. I also thought that he didn’t exist, but no - this is him